# PHP - issue passing array to JSON - JSTree

Tags: php, json, ajax

Just a tedious problem i'm having when trying to pass an array in JSON within an AJAX call..I'm trying to add the link attribute to the array according to JSTree required format....

This works...without using a seperate php file...

```
$('#jstree').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'data' : [{"id":"1","name":"services","text":"Services","parent_id":"0","a_attr":{"href":"www.google.com"}}]
    }    
});
```

But when using PHP file...

```
$('#jstree').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'data' : {
            'url' : "response.php", 
            'data' : function (node) {
                return { 'id' : node.id };
            },
            "dataType" : "json"
        }
    },
});
```

the php file...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tree`";
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) { 
    $row['a_attr']->href =  "www.google.com";
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

this is producing the following result..

```
[{"id":"1","name":"services","text":"Services","parent_id":"0","a_attr":{"href":"www.google.com"}}]
```

which is exactly what i want but...the jstree is not accepting this..

When i remove the a_attr addition in the code... it works but obviously there is no longer the attr i need in the array.. 
When checking the json output on the PHP file..I do get an warning message:

Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\xampp\htdocs\noc\response.php on line 15

But I'm clueless and require some help if anyone would give a hand...

Comment: The warning is probably that you did not initialize $data ie at the top put `$data = array();`

Comment: is possible that the warning message from php damage the output.... try removing warnings at runtime: "  error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);  " just to see if that's the case ...

Comment: Thanks Federico, the error IS damaging the output.. Soon as i insert the error reporting the code works... the array initialize doesnt though...nerfdlist..
hmmmm.

Comment: The line that throws the errors is 
$row['a_attr']->href =  "www.google.com";
Think it has something to do with stdClass definition...looking through pages on S.O